# How to create and modify SDF file?

Tags: gazebo-tutorial, gazebo-1.5, sdformat

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

As in the topic.
I'm trying to follow tutorial on gazebosim.org but I don't know how to create SDF file.
I have installed Vim Gnome but I still can't open/modify such a file.

Can anyone recommend me any program or other solution?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/2192/how-to-create-and-modify-sdf-file?/) by [MoonWalker](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/248/moonwalker/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 17 on 2013-04-02

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

A sdf file is just a text file with a sdf extension. You can create it with any text editor (that doesn't add extra characters). You should be able to type `vim new_sdf.sdf` in a terminal, which will open the editor. Or use `gedit new_sdf.sdf` if you want a non terminal editor.

---

Originally posted by [Davinci](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/108/davinci/) with karma: 65 on 2013-04-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1